# Trigger $(window).scroll behavior further down for smaller resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using `$(window).scroll` to pop up a little, fixed, footer-like overlay at the bottom of the screen when a user scrolls down a bit, as in:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 10){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "0" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "-1000px"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 11){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "1" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "0"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "1" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "-1000px"});
}
});
```

That will slide in the overlay when the user scrolls down a bit and when they reach towards the bottom of the page, slide it out again.

That works fine when the screen is at larger resolutions but at smaller resolutions, when responsive kicks in and the layout changes, the overlay is covering some things I don't want it to cover. Is it possible to have the script monitor window width and at smaller widths trigger the overlay further down? So, let's say at, for example, a width of 900 or less, we switch to --

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "0" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "-1000px"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 301){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "1" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "0"});
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
    $("#giveaway-wrapper").css({"opacity": "1" , "position": "fixed", "bottom": "-1000px"});
}
});
```

-- which will trigger the overlay to slide in further down at that resolution and below.

HTML is along the lines of:

```
<div id="giveaway-wrapper">
        <img src="images/giveaway.png">
        <div id="giveaway-background">
            <div id="giveaway" class="content">
                <h3>...lorem ipsum...</h3>
            </div>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide HTML?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The HTML is probably not hugely critical. The script will essentially trigger whatever is in #giveaway-wrapper to fire, but I've added it to the question. I would just like that script to fire lower down on the page once the resolution drops below a certain point.

Comment: Can you please provide your code exactly in the snippet? We can get a clear picture.